# Can't use ActiveX component, built on Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, activex

I have an ActiveX control that I build in Visual Studio. But once registered, it cannot be used. Specific examples:

1. It builds on Visual Studio 17 with all the latest updates, successfully registers and controls can be used, for example, in RadStudio, in Visual Basic, in C # in the studio, etc.
2. It builds on Visual Studio 19 with all the latest updates, registers successfully, but RadStudio does not see it. And in VisualBasic, the component is visible, but when you try to add it to the form, an "Unspecified Error" error pops up. At the same time, everything is ok in the studio in C #: everything sees and works.

At the same time, the source codes are absolutely the same, all those compilation flags, linking, etc. What could be the reason?

Comment: May be time to move on to something more modern. Or stay with the build platform that works.

Comment: Yes, I share your point of view 100%, but the terms of reference oblige me to figure this out and fix the problem. ActiveX still assumes that the components will be compatible, so it's strange that this error occurs..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I found reason. Somehow in  my vs2019 **PreferredToolArchitecture** was set to **x64** instead of **x86**. By changing it to **x86** everything becomes good.